# Why do this error appear "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint "?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE postcodes (
    postcode_ID INT NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (postcode_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE countries (
    country_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country_name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (country_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    supplier_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    supplier_name VARCHAR(50), 
    supplier_forename VARCHAR(50),
    supplier_phonenumber VARCHAR(20),
    supplier_address VARCHAR(50), 
    supplier_postcode INT,
    supplier_country INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_postcode) REFERENCES postcode(postcode_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_country) REFERENCES countries(country_ID)
) ;
```

Comment: do: `show engine status innodb`. buried near the middle of the output is a "last foreign key error" section. it'll have more details about why you got the error. If you're on an older mysql, one major reason for getting this error was forgetting to put indexes on the fields in the "child" table (e.g. `supplier_postcode` and `supplier_country` must be indexed for FKs to work)

Comment: How do i put indexes on supplier_postcode and supplier_country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo:

```
CREATE TABLE postcodes (
                     ^----plural

    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_postcode) REFERENCES postcode(postcode_ID), 
                                                       ^----no S, singular
```

You're trying to reference a table which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you :) I think i'm blind!